# How do I make a round hole in overlapping cement board wall with limited access?

Tags: walls, ventilation, construction, remodeling

I am having a hard time planning a hole for a one room in wall ventilator.
I have already a 160mm hole in my exterior wall. However, on the outside the wall is covered in 3-mm square cement board façade. The cement boards are nailed to a wood frame in an overlapping manner. Looking from the inside at the end of the hole in the wall I see the cement boards and some bits of the wood frame.

I have very limited access to the wall from outside - 7m from the ground, don't want to buy a ladder which would cost upwards of 250EUR. I can reach to the place via a near by window, but with no real working capabilities.

What is the best way to get a round hole in the overlapping cement boards working mainly from the inside?

My current idea is to run a threaded rod through the center of the hole.
Attach an OSB plate with an OSB ring on it pressing on the cement boards.
Then using chisel to break the hole in the boards from inside through the hole in the wall.

Any suggestions on how to improve the results?

Any excess broken cement board will leave an ugly spot on the façade. Any repair work on the face will require access to the spot from the exterior. On the other side, I don't believe it's possible what I want to achieve. So any damage limiting suggestions would also help.

[image]
NOTE: the inside is on the left, outside on the right.

Comment: Can rent ladders or even better a man lift(safe) and any nice tools you might want/need by the hour/day/week, in most places.

Comment: I presume "Brick wall" is on the outside and  "OSB plate" is on the inside, correct? How much room between the cement board & the brick wall? Where is the wood frame you mention? What's to prevent you from simply using a hole saw to cut the hole instead of chiseling it out? As noted above, you can usually rent/hire tools for a few hours or a day to get the job done.

Comment: @crip659 - thanks, sure, renting a ladder could be an option, but a 7m high ladder even as a 3part ladder does not fit into my car. So renting the ladder means renting a larger car. But what machine would even cut such brittle slim concrete plates. which are overlayed and have some movement possibilities.

Comment: @FreeMan - no no, in the picture, left from the wall is my "inside" - the room, right side is the exterior. The OSB construction is my attempt to hold the plates while I chisel them from the inside. Holesaw for such plates... they are really brittle, not sure I could cut a hole in them free hands.

Comment: Ah! Some extra labeling on your diagram would be helpful, then! :) Also, where is the wood you mention? I think you'd be surprised at what you could do with a diamond grit hole saw. Light pressure, just enough to keep the saw in contact with the siding shouldn't push them away from the wall. Just let the grit do its job and grind through. You'll end up with a much cleaner hole than if you bang at it with a chisel - I've got similar type siding on my house and efforts to break the siding often end up with cracks running everywhere.

Comment: BTW, if you don't have access to the outside, how are you going to get the OSB ring & backing plate on the outside of the wall to execute your plan?

Comment: Can buy or probably rent roof racks for your car, quite a few just clamp on.

Comment: Once you've made the hole (by whatever means) if you don't have access to the outside how do you intend to weather-seal it to prevent rainwater coming in around the edges between the hole and whatever you push through it? To do this job properly you should be putting something like flashing up underneath the overlap on the next higher board and also sealing all around the edges. You really do need a ladder or lift to do this job.

Comment: You can borrow a larger vehicle from a friend, or rent one.

Comment: @FreeMan - I can access it via a near by window, but only to the extent to work with one hand. Of course - I could rent, buy, lend everything needed, but then I would blow the cost for this tiny hole to an extent I have not planned and am not really willing to spend for it :)

Comment: @brhans - have very limited access, but enough to apply so sealant, to install the outside cover of the venting unit, to paint over etc... (everything that can be done with 1 hand while hanging out the window)